# How to tell Detox to wait for my elements to appear

Tags: react-native, detox

My view takes a second to load in after an event.
When calling:

`expect(element(by.id('my-view'))).toBeVisible()`

sometimes detox finds this element and sometimes it does not.
How do I tell detox to wait for the elements to appear?

Comment: Shooting in the dark here, but have you applied an `await` before the `expect()...toBeVisible()`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `waitFor` function with a timeout you define:

`await waitFor(element(by.id('my-view'))).toBeVisible().withTimeout(5000)`

this tells detox to wait 5000ms before failing.

See example here: https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.RunningTests.md#test-tries-to-find-my-component-before-its-created

Comment: I'm really surprised that Detox doesn't auto-wait by default on every assertion. Seems like a basic requirement for any test automation framework.